# Elliptic curves with same number of points as field order

Tags: finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Is it possible for an elliptic curve defined over a finite field $\mathrm{GF}(p^k)$ to have $p^k$ points? If not, what is the highest possible $m$ such that there is an elliptic curve over $\mathrm{GF}(p^k)$ with number of points divisible by $p^m$?

Comment: It is possible for an elliptic curve defined over $F_{p^k}$ to have $p^k$ points. you can get a bound from Hasse's theorem.

Comment: @math $p^k$ is in the range of values allowed by Hasse's theorem, but I didn't think that Hasse's theorem guaranteed the existence of elliptic curves for any number of points in $[p^k + 1 - 2 p^{k/2}, p^k + 1 + 2 p^{k/2}]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following reference gives a detailed study for such curves defined over $\Bbb F_q$, having $q$ $\Bbb F_q$-rational points:

[CM-CURVES WITH GOOD CRYPTOGRAPHIC PROPERTIES, Neal Koblitz, in J. Feigenbaum (Ed.): Advances in Cryptology - CRYPT0 '91, LNCS 576, pp. 279-287, 1992. (@) Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 1992](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-46766-1_22.pdf)

Koblitz, following Mazur, calls them **anomalous**.

The $\Bbb F_q$-points are closely related to the action of the corresponding Frobenius morphism, their number is then related to its characteristic polynomial,
and the trace of the Frobenius is the coefficient needed, if it is one we have an anomalous elliptic curve. A search with the favorite search engine for "anomalous elliptic curves" produces numerous hits.

(This could not be edited as a comment, so it is submitted as an answer.)